# Calling data from a list

Tags: c#, sql, visual-foxpro

I have been writing a program to pull data from an SQL server database, and push to a Visual Foxpro database, but I've hit a snag.

I've defined the connection to the two servers:

```
var exportConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString:
    "Data Source=Localhost;"
    + "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
    + @"connection timeout=30;"
    + @"database=001-CARL_V4");

var importConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString:
    "Data Source=Localhost;"
    + @"connection timeout=30;"
    + @"Provider=vfpoledb.1;"
    + @"data source=C:\Users\Joshua.cameron\Desktop\PCHomesImportTestBlank\PCHomesServer\DATABASE\pchomes.dbc");
```

I've tested these two, no issue.

I've pulled data from the SQL server using accessors:

```
 public string OwTitle { get; set; }
 public string OwForenames { get; set; }
 public string OwSurname { get; set; }
```

and assigned these values to a list:

```
ImportArray[] exportArray = null;

SqlCommand exportCommand = new SqlCommand(@"select * from dbo.CARL_Owners", exportConnection);
{
    exportConnection.Open();
    using (var exportReader = exportCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Populating Array...");
        try
        {

            var list = new List<ImportArray>();
            //while(exportReader.Read())
            var read = exportReader.Read();
            list.Add(item: new ImportArray
            {
                OwTitle = exportReader.GetValue(0).ToString(),
                OwForenames = exportReader.GetValue(1).ToString(),
                OwSurname = exportReader.GetValue(2).ToString(),                          
            });

            exportArray = list.ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine("Array populated");
           // Console.Write(list);
            Console.ReadKey();
```

I'm then trying to pull data from the list and push it to the FoxPro Table

```
try
{
    importConnection.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Foxpro connection open");
    OleDbCommand deleteOleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand(@"TRUNCATE TABLE CLIENT",
        importConnection);

    Console.WriteLine("writing to table");
    Console.ReadKey();
    using (
        var importCommand =
            new OleDbCommand(
                string.Format(@"INSERT INTO CLIENT (Title,Fname,Sname) VALUES ({0},{1},{2}",
                    exportReader.GetValue(0), exportReader.GetValue(1), exportReader.GetValue(2)),
                importConnection))
    {
        importCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.Write("Foxpro Database unreachable");
    Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
}
finally
{
    importConnection.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("Connection closed");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This is where the problem occurs. It almost seems like it's skipping part of this section.

[Output running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zJzR.png)

as you can see from the output, it doesn't even display the Console.writeline("writing to table") section.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried [debugging your code](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: You seem to put the data into an object named list and then try to export them using the Datareader you used to read the data from the other server... Maybe in the string. format you have to use the list object instead of using the exportreader, also, maybe you need to made a cycle for each element in the list collection...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am adding another answer here, as your other question is (unfortunately) closed (I don't know why they do that). I placed explanations as comments in between. Please close your existing questions first.

```
void Main()
{
  using (var exportConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString: "Data Source=Localhost;"
                                                                   + "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
                                                                   + @"connection timeout=30;"
                                                                   + @"database=001-CARL_V4"))

  // your importConnection was wrong
  using (var importConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString: @"Provider=vfpoledb.1;"
                                                               + @"data source=C:\Users\Joshua.cameron\Desktop\PCHomesImportTestBlank\PCHomesServer\DATABASE\pchomes.dbc"))

  using (SqlCommand exportCommand = new SqlCommand(@"select * from dbo.CARL_Owners", exportConnection))

  using (OleDbCommand importCommand = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO CLIENT (itle,Fname,Sname) VALUES (?,?,?)",
        importConnection))
  {
    // you shouldn't use an array in between
    // because if the data is large you would be unnecessarily
    // wasting memory. Instead fill the rows in VFP database 
    // as you read data from SQL with the reader.
    // IOW do the process streaming. Read -> insert 
    // You are doing: Read into an array -> insert from array 
    // (but erroneously attempting to read from the reader again)


    importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Title", "");
    importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Fname", "");
    importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Sname", "");

    // Open connections to both
    exportConnection.Open();
    importConnection.Open();

    Console.WriteLine("Visual Foxpro connection open");
    new OleDbCommand(@"DELETE FROM CLIENT", importConnection).ExecuteNonQuery();

    Console.WriteLine("Writing to table");
    Console.ReadKey();


    // Initiate the reader to SQL
    var exportReader = exportCommand.ExecuteReader();

    // Start reading
    while (exportReader.Read())
    {
      // as you read rows from SQL, set the parameter values
      // I would suggest using (string)row["sourceColumn"]
      // style but reader.GetValue, reader.GetString(index)
      // would work as well - although not safe (what happens
      // if someone modifies the structure of the SQL table a bit?)

      // anyway set the values
      importCommand.Parameters["Title"].Value = exportReader.GetString(0);
      importCommand.Parameters["Fname"].Value = exportReader.GetString(1);
      importCommand.Parameters["Sname"].Value = exportReader.GetString(2);

      // insert into VFP
      importCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    // done
    exportConnection.Close();
    importConnection.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I take it that I don't need to specify Localhost on a VFP connection? Or is that because I have specified the data source?

Comment: Data source is NOT "localhost" but the fullpath to dbc (in last line). A VFPOLED connection is simply: "Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=< path to files >".

Comment: BTW, for the SQL server too, instead of Localhost, it is safer to use just a . (dot).

Comment: Apologies for all the questions.
The code has input data now, but it's come out as numbers, not the words it should be. Any idea why?

Comment: Because you are using reader.GetValue and your SQL is "select * from ...". That means first 3 columns in SQL result would be set as values. I told you before and tried to explain in code that it is unsafe. Instead, do something like "Select title, firstName, lastName from .,.." for the SQL string so you know exactly what columns you are retrieving. Then in the part where you set values, instead of reader.GetValue(index) use (string)reader["ColumnName"],

Answer (score 1):

This question is related to your other question. VFP doesn't have "Truncate table" command, you need to quote the values and better yet you need to use parameters. Here is a revised code connecting both questions:

```
void Main()
{
  using (var exportConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString:
      "Data Source=Localhost;"
      + "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
      + @"connection timeout=30;"
      + @"database=001-CARL_V4"))
  using (var importConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString:
      @"Provider=vfpoledb.1;" +
      @"data source=C:\Users\Joshua.cameron\Desktop\PCHomesImportTestBlank\PCHomesServer\DATABASE\pchomes.dbc"))
  using (OleDbCommand importCommand = new OleDbCommand(
      @"INSERT INTO CLIENT (Title,Fname,Sname) VALUES (?,?,?)",
      importConnection))
  using (SqlCommand exportCommand = new SqlCommand(@"select 
      title as [title], firstName as [fname], lastName as [sname] 
      from dbo.CARL_Owners", exportConnection))
  {
    importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("title", "");
    importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("fname", "");
    importCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("sname", "");

    {
      importConnection.Open();
      Console.WriteLine("Foxpro connection open");
      new OleDbCommand(@"Delete from CLIENT", importConnection).ExecuteNonQuery();

      Console.WriteLine("writing to table");
      exportConnection.Open();

      var exportReader = exportCommand.ExecuteReader();
      while (exportReader.Read())
      {
        importCommand.Parameters["title"].Value = (string)exportReader["title"];
        importCommand.Parameters["fname"].Value = (string)exportReader["fname"];
        importCommand.Parameters["sname"].Value = (string)exportReader["sname"];
        importCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
      importConnection.Close();
      exportConnection.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

You could also create the connection from within VFP code to SQL server, thus doing a better optimized insert in one go using "ExecScript". ie:

```
void Main()
{
  var vfpCode = @"
  local lnHandle
  lnHandle = SQLStringConnect('driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'+;
      'server=.;Trusted_Connection=yes;database=001-CARL_V4')
  SQLExec( m.lnHandle, ;
   'select  title as [title], firstName as [fname], lastName as [sname] from CARL_Owners', ;
   'crsOwners')
  SQLDisconnect(0)


  * if you can use exclusive locks then:
  * zap    
  * assuming you cant

  delete from Client
  insert into Client (Title,Fname,Sname) ;
      select Title,Fname,Sname from crsOwners";


  using (var importConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString:
      @"Provider=vfpoledb.1;" +
      @"data source=C:\Users\Joshua.cameron\Desktop\PCHomesImportTestBlank\PCHomesServer\DATABASE\pchomes.dbc"))
  {
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("ExecScript", importConnection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("code", vfpCode);

    importConnection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    importConnection.Close();
  }
}
```

PS: Please note that I assumed you had field names as title, firstName, lastName on MS SQL.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two possible problems with your code.

1. I think you are not executing the deleteOleDbCommand. You initialized it but you did not execute that command anywhere.
2. @"INSERT INTO CLIENT (Title,Fname,Sname) VALUES ({0},{1},{2}". There is end bracket missing in your query. It should be like 
   @"INSERT INTO CLIENT (Title,Fname,Sname) VALUES ({0},{1},{2})"

These two can be possible problems with your code.

Comment: agreed, but why is the code jumping from `Console.WriteLine("Foxpro connection open");` to `Console.WriteLine("Connection closed");` with no output inbetween?

Comment: Have u tried debugging?
Because it is an unusual behavior. It will only be possible if an exception is thrown at the time of initializing the Command Object. Which is also abnormal. Place a checkpoint at the line where you are printing "Writing into table".
See where the control shifts next. Only then I will be able to identify what is the error.

Comment: So now I seem to be getting a syntax error, not sure why.

I've put in a breakpoint on the import command, it's listing a record count of 97, so it's picking data up.

[link](http://imgur.com/Hml2mxV)

Comment: Adding in the missing bracket seemed to allow the program to step in, thanks for pointing that one out.

Comment: You are welcome. Comment if you find any other mistake. May I will be able to help